# What am I doing wrong with this define_method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, metaprogramming

Ok so i want to have a named_scope for all the types like the following

```
class Variety < ActiveRecord::Base
  TYPES = ["holiday", "party", "other", yet_another]

  Variety::TYPES.each do |role|
    define_method
      scope "#{role.to_sym}_applications", where(:type => role)
    end
  end
end
```

Basically I want the named scopes defined meta programmatically so that I can do this

```
Variety.holiday_applications
Variety.party_applications
Variety.other_applications
Variety.yet_another_applications
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong with the define method

Comment: you don't need the define_method.

Comment: I noticed that ...posting my solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving your to_sym to the entire method name.

```
scope "#{role}_applications".to_sym, where(:type => role)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Variety::TYPES.each do |role|
   scope "#{role}_applications".to_sym, where(:type => role)
 end
```

Comment: Solved it ...and it only took 6 minutes :)